# How to arrange two data frame in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames in R as follows:

```
 dat1<-read.table (text=" ID Surname Name Class
    12  Smith   Bani B
    14  Smith   Adami C
    13  Rose    Road AB
    11  Smith   Cherch AC
    10  Sarah   Naim D

    ", header=TRUE)

    dat2<-read.table (text=" ID Surname Name Class
    12  Smith   Bani A
    14  Smith   Adami B
    13  Rose    Road AB
    11  Smith   Cherch AC
    10  Sarah   Naim D

    ", header=TRUE)
```

I arrange like this separately

```
k1 <- arrange(dat1, Surname)
k2 <- arrange(dat2, Surname)
```

Now I merge dat1 and dat2 followed  by arranging

```
k3 <- merge(dat1, dat2, by = "ID")
k4 <- arrange(k3, Surname.x)
```

I want to get exactly the arrangement that I get for  K1 or K2 for the surname when I merge dat1 and dat2. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::inner_join` to get the same order.

```
dplyr::inner_join(k1, k2, by = 'ID')

#  ID Surname.x Name.x Class.x Surname.y Name.y Class.y
#1 13      Rose   Road      AB      Rose   Road      AB
#2 10     Sarah   Naim       D     Sarah   Naim       D
#3 12     Smith   Bani       B     Smith   Bani       A
#4 14     Smith  Adami       C     Smith  Adami       B
#5 11     Smith Cherch      AC     Smith Cherch      AC
```

Answer (score 1):

We could consider using `base R` (`R 4.1.0`) by creating a sequence column in one of the datasets before the `merge` and then do the `order`

```
merge(transform(k1, rn = seq_along(ID)), k2, by = 'ID') |> 
     {\(dat) dat[order(dat$rn), setdiff(names(dat), 'rn')]}()
  ID Surname.x Name.x Class.x Surname.y Name.y Class.y
4 13      Rose   Road      AB      Rose   Road      AB
1 10     Sarah   Naim       D     Sarah   Naim       D
3 12     Smith   Bani       B     Smith   Bani       A
5 14     Smith  Adami       C     Smith  Adami       B
2 11     Smith Cherch      AC     Smith Cherch      AC
```